# How can I pass bass and it's derived classes object's in a same method?

Tags: c++

Let's say I've a class fruit and several class like apple,mango etc,Now i want to create a single function that would accept fruit and it's all derived classes object's as argument,How can i do so?

I have not tried anything yet!

Comment: Make the parameter a pointer or reference to base class. Search for *"dynamic binding"* in your favorite [c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: `void eat(Fruit const& fruit){ ... }` (or remove the `const`, if you need to modify the fruit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the function parameter to be a *reference or a pointer to the base class* as shown below.

```
void eat(const Fruit* f)
{
    //code here
}
```

Or

```
void eat(const Fruit& f)
{
   //code here
}
```

You can remove the low-level const if you want to be able to make changes through `f`.